# AWS s3, hide/disable serving the web.config file

Tags: amazon-s3, web.config

Currently we have a site setup in an s3 bucket.
This site makes use of a web.config file.

However we can navigate to the file via the url:
for example, `www.mysite.com/web.config` will serve the file.

Is there a simple way to avoid the web.config to be served via this method? On IIS this is automatically secure as well as in apache (for .htaccess files)

Comment: Why are you putting the `web.config` file in the bucket in the first place? It won't do anything on S3.

Comment: In any case, would there be a way to hide/secure this file? Assume it's not a web.config file and a different file instead

Comment: Sure, you can edit the file's permissions individually, or set overall IAM rules. You'll see various options to do this in the S3 console. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/set-object-permissions.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your site actually needs a `web.config` file, then your site isn't suitable for hosting on S3.

> You can host a static website on Amazon Simple Storage Service (Amazon S3). On a static website, individual webpages include static content. They might also contain client-side scripts. By contrast, a dynamic website relies on server-side processing, including server-side scripts such as PHP, JSP, or ASP.NET. Amazon S3 does not support server-side scripting.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html

If, on the other hand, your site doesn't actually need the web.config file, then the file should not be uploaded to a public S3 bucket.

It is possible to deny access to files by name patterns using the bucket policy, or by not setting `public-read` for the object itself (assuming the bucket policy doesn't make this setting redundant)... but this solves the wrong problem.

Comment: We ended up removing the file itself.

Answer (score 0):

@Malky.Kid, could you share what approach you took for removing the file and from where did you configure the variables present in that file. I am also facing a similar scenario.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/537495)